# Exe from python issue

Tags: python, tkinter, keyboard, pyinstaller, hotkeys

So, I've recently made a software with some basic GUI in Python. I wanted to add also hotkeys, therefore I used module **keyboard**. Then I "exported" the program to .exe application. On my working PC it worked flawlessly, but when I tried to run it on another PC, without Python installed (which was my main target), the hotkeys didn't seem to work quite properly; when I pressed the key, the app fell down, closed itself...

I'm not sure why it did happen like this, the **keyboard** module should be included in output file. I'm using *pyinstaller*.

Do you have any clue how to deal with it?

Comment: run it from the command line and see what the error is ... if you double click it you will not see the output after it crashes

Comment: I'm not sure how you mean it. When I run it in cmd (start file.exe) it starts, but when it crashes, no error is written in cmd, only pop-up window appears **program file.exe has stopped working**... And now I noticed, that it also fails when I press keys binded in canvas.bind()-way, besides that from keyboard

Comment: @JoranBeasley Does it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out by avoiding *keyboard* completely. The problem was, as if pyinstaller couldn't include the module properly, so I just rewrote the code using **canvas.bind()** function.